# Need to dynamically change fill pattern

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fill

I have done this code: http://www.cozeez.co.uk/test.php

How do I change the fill image from 3 buttons to 3 different colors?

Comment: @Neal: I need to have 3 buttons that will change those images in the circles to different images

Comment: I think you're missing some code. There aren't 3 buttons...

Comment: @Lee one min ill make a fiddle

Comment: jsfiddle is slowww... idk why its going so slow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add three buttons with id 'button1', 'button2', 'button3'

Rewrite your current code so you dont repeat yourself (DRY):

```
function fillCircle(canvasId, color) {
    var canvas=document.getElementById(canvasId);
    var cxt=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var imageObj = new Image();
    imageObj.src = "images/" + color + ".jpg";
    imageObj.onload = function() {
        var pattern = cxt.createPattern(imageObj, "repeat");
        cxt.fillStyle=pattern;
        cxt.fill();
    }


    cxt.beginPath();
    cxt.arc(51,51,50,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    cxt.closePath();
    cxt.stroke();
} 

fillCircle("myCanvas", "pink");
fillCircle("myCanvas2", "green");
```

And add (with jQuery): EDITED

```
$('#button1').click(function() {fillCircle("myCanvas", "blue")});
$('#button2').click(function() {fillCircle("myCanvas", "red")});
$('#button3').click(function() {fillCircle("myCanvas", "yellow")});
```

Or whatever colors you want, and depending on which canvas you want to change of course.

Comment: I made an error in the events, please use the new three bottom lines.

Comment: Also, I think there was an error in your code that I didn't see - the event handler "onload" should be set before you change the "src" attribute. Or else the handler is too late and executes on the next time the src attribute is set.

Comment: It seems to be working now, all circles can be changed individually. Do you have any more issues before closing this?